# Combine Categories & Custom Taxonomy

Tags: customization, permalinks, taxonomy

I want to combine the category URL with a taxonomy.

So for example now the URL is: `domain.com/category/?district=citycentre`
I want to make this URL like this: `domain.com/category/citycentre`

Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible but your category permalink for normal categories wont be available since you will overwrite it with your custom rewrite rule.

Comment: Is there a other solution like for example domain.com/category/district/citycentre ? 

The url is for example: domain.com/restaurants/district/citycentre

Answer (score 0):

For following post type and taxonomy:

```
/**
 * Register restaurant post type
 */
function wpse_287682_register_restaurant_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'Restaurants' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Restaurant' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add new' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add new' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'Not found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Not found Restaurants in trash' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Restaurants' ),

    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
        'taxonomies' => array(),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'restaurant' ),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
    );

    register_post_type( 'restaurant', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpse_287682_register_restaurant_post_type' );

/**
 * Register district taxonomy
 */
function wpse_287682_register_district_taxonomy() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'              => __( 'Districts' ),
        'singular_name'     => __( 'District' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Districts' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Districts' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent District' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent District:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit District' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update District' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New District' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New District Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'District' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'district' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'district', array( 'restaurant' ), $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpse_287682_register_district_taxonomy', 0 );
```

You can add this kind of rewrite rule.

```
/**
 * Add custom rewrite rule for restaurant post type and district taxonomy.
 *
 * Remember to flush rewrite rules to apply changes.
 */
function wpse_287682_add_restaurant_district_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('restaurant/district/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=restaurant&district=$matches[1]', 'top');
}

add_action('init', 'wpse_287682_add_restaurant_district_rewrite_rule');
```

Your link for citycenter district will be:
`http://example.com/restaurant/district/citycenter/`.

Remember to flush rewrite rules after code update.